# Salesforce Approval Process - ProcessInstanceWorkitem use ActorId manager after Reassign

Tags: case, approval-process, sales-process

It's possible use the **ActorId manager** during the approval steps instead of the initial approver's manager (OriginalActorId) after reassign?